# Get Image based on Sort Order

Tags: magento-1.8, ce-1.9.0.1

I am trying to change the image on hover for product in listing page for one of our Magento Eshop. I can change the image on hover. What i did was i used small and thumbnail image for it and changed it using mouseenter and mouseleave event.

But now i want to change it based on sort order. Say the image with Sort Order 2 should be visible on hover.

I am not sure how to do it ? Could anyone please guide me on this. From where shall i start ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve it. I am pasting the code below for what i did.

Step 1 : Created an helper file and have added this code in there

```
<?php
class Greeting_Products_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
    function altImage($product, $val, $w, $h, $imgVersion='small_image'){
    $product->load('media_gallery');
    $column = 'position';
    $value = $val;
    $gal = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();
    if ($gal = $product->getMediaGalleryImages())
    {
        if ($altImg = $gal->getItemByColumnValue($column, $value))
        {
            return
            '<img class="alt-img lazyOwl"  style="display:none;" src="' . $this->getImg($product, $w, $h, $imgVersion, $altImg->getFile()) . '" alt="' . $product->getName() . '" />';

        }
    }
    return '';
}

}
?>
```

Please review the code. It will pretty much explain everything.

To call the alternative image use the following code :

```
echo $this->helper('greeting_products')->altImage($_product,2,220,220);
```

Here 2 is the position of image and rest are the image parameters

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below code you can got the all detail of your media Gallery with sort id. Then after you can manage as per your requirement.

```
 <?php 
     $prod=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(1);
     foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $_image){
        print_r($_image));    
     }
 ?>
```

Hope you got the proper Solution.

Comment: i guess you are talking about getMediaGalleryImages()... i tried it... but the thing is how can i get the URL of the image whose position is say 2?... could you please let me know on it

Answer (score 0):

here total solution:
first all gallery images of products:

```
$Product=Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load(51);
$ImageColl=$Product->getMediaGallery('images');
```

Second: `exclude disabled images from gallery image collection and sort by default positio`n

```
$sorter=array();
$ret=array();
$key='position_default';
 reset($ImageColl);

    foreach ($ImageColl as $ii => $image) {
        if($image['disabled']){
        continue;
        }
        $sorter[$ii]=$image[$key];
    }
    asort($sorter);
```

third: to get  second gallery image:

```
$j=0;
$secondimg='';
foreach ($sorter as $ii => $va) {

    $ret[$ii]=$ImageColl[$ii];
    if($j==1){
        $secondimg=$ImageColl[$ii];
    }
    if($j>1){
        break;
    }
    $j++;
}
```

and $secondimg gives second image

```
  echo "<pre>";
print_r($secondimg);
echo "</pre>";
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may use built in Magento's functionality

```
$_subImages = $_product->getMediaGalleryImages('images')->setOrder('position','ASC');
foreach ($_subImages as $imgKey => $subimage) {
    #Your code 
}
```